# How can I reset the network settings on Ubuntu server 18?

Tags: networking, server, virtualization

So I messed up on my network settings on my Ubuntu server virtualmachine but I don't remember what I did and I'd like to know how to reset my network settings back to default?

Comment: How did you (mis)configure your network settings? What did you do?

Comment: I don't remember,i think i went through some configuration files or something i don't exactly remember what i did.

Comment: Did you use GUI or terminal ?